# Printing Initial Letters of Words

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, dictionary

My question set is shown below:

Write a function named `initialDict` that takes a string, `text`, as a parameter and computes and returns a dictionary in which each initial letter of a word in `text` is a key. All keys should be lower cased. The value of each key is a list of all words in `text` beginning with that letter.

**Input:** `text`, a string

**Return:** a dictionary of initial letter:word list pairs

For example, the following would be correct output.

```
print(initialDict('The Call of the Wild'))
{'c':['Call'], 't':['The', 'the'], 'w':['Wild'], 'o':['of']}
```

---

So far I have this and am not sure if I'm on track or not:

```
def initialDict(text):
    dic = {}
    text.lower()
    text.split()
    for i in word:
```

---

I've tried one thing but it just ran an error.

Comment: What makes you think you are not on the right track?

Comment: I'm not very good with writing functions for dictionaries. I mean I feel like I am for the most part on the right track but I don't know how to go about it. I've tried one thing but it just ran an error.

Comment: how would i go about the rest of it?

Comment: Please include the text here, not in a picture, so that everything is in one place and easy to read. Make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

`str.lower()` and `str.split()` don't change their inputs directly, since strings are immutable in Python.

This looks like an assignment, so a hint rather than a full implementation: to iterate over the words, you'd combine those calls.

```
for word in text.lower().split():
    # do something to 'word' here
```

For the other parts of the question:

- To get the first letter, look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings), especially the part saying "Strings can be *indexed*..."
- To make the lists, look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), especially the part saying "You can also add new items..."

Hope that helps. The tutorial at [docs.python.org/3/tutorial/](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) is a wonderful resource as well.

Comment: Thank you.  This is just a review for an exam that isn't being handed in.  So I need to add the first letter of each word to the dictionary as keys and then each word that starts with that letter will be added to the dictionary as the values.  I haven't done much in adding to dictionaries like this so it's very confusing.

Comment: Don't i have to use index 0 of each word to pull that out, but then how do i add that in as a key and then add the values

Comment: You can check whether a key already exists with `if my_key in my_dict:`. If it doesn't, you should add a new list. Then you can put your word into the list.